# If the word content increases , how to get to next line on p tag

Tags: html, css

I want the word content of paragraph element to get to next line if the word content exceeds the screen. How to achieve this using css styles?

Here is what I have tried

**template.html**

```
  <div class="rightDiv">
   <input id="inputCustomer">
   <p id="spandiv" [ngStyle]="{'position':'absolute','left':'60px'}" >{{customerName}}</p>
  </div>
```

**template.css**

```
.rightDiv {
 position: relative;
 right: 320px;
 height: 80px;
 width: 160px;
}

#spandiv {
  top: 40px;
  background-color: #6B6664;
  padding: 5px;
  color:white;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  opacity:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word!important; // this is not working

}


 #inputCustomer:hover + #spandiv {
  display: block;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: You can add "word-break: break-all" in  your text tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the white-space in th css `#spandiv` like that:

```css
    #spandiv {
      top: 40px;
      background-color: #6B6664;
      padding: 5px;
      color:white;
      font-weight: normal;
      display: block;
      opacity:0;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: auto;
      word-wrap: break-all;
      white-space: normal;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jorge thats perfect , but what is the difference between word-wrap and white- space

Comment: 'white-space: normal' 
it is used so that the text fits the container respecting the space that you have left with margin or padding, making the text behave fluidly and jump out of line when running out of space due precisely to the fact that you have previously delimited it. Sorry if my english is not perfect.

Comment: Thats perfect but what about word-wrap: break-all;

Comment: 'break-all' breaks every word when the space has been finished

Comment: word-wrap: break-all;white-space: normal; both seems to be same for me, if I remove either of them , expected behavior is lost! Why do think I need both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Use **break-all** instead of **break-word**. If you want to break word

```
#spandiv {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following css to the `<p>` tag

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
hyphens: auto;
```

Demo is here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/